# Python Flask - request.data.get

Tags: python, rest, flask, request

I have been asked to understand and maintain code like the following code block.

```
@app.route("/api/v1/users/register/", methods=["POST"])
def register():
    data = {
        "lat": request.data.get("lat", ""),
        "lon": request.data.get("lon", ""),
        "is_bl_allowed": request.data.get("is_bl_allowed", 1),
        "is_loc_allowed": request.data.get("is_loc_allowed", 1),
        "is_bl_on": request.data.get("is_bl_on", 1),
        "is_loc_on": request.data.get("is_loc_on", 1)
    }
```

Imports are

```
from flask import make_response
from flask import request, jsonify
import requests
```

I thought flask request used get_json or form.get to retrive POST request data.
I am not sure what is being retrieved in this code block. I do not have access to the code that is calling this API.
If anyone can explain what the **request.data.get** does, what its return value would be and why it takes 2 parameters, that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a post request like this, the `request.data` attribute is like a dictionary. If you have a dictionary in python you can use `get` to specify a key you want the value for in the dictionary, for example:

```
example = {"key": "value"}
example.get("key")  # gives you "value"
```

The difference between using `get` and simply doing `example["key"]` is that you won't get and error of the key is missing:

```
example = {"key": "value"}
example.get("other")  # gives you None
example["other"]  # raises KeyError
```

You can also (as in your example) give a default value for a missing key:

```
example = {"key": "value"}
example.get("key")  # gives you "value"
example.get("other", "different value")  # gives you "different value"
```

So, for your end point the code is trying to get a series of data points from the post request using `data.get` and is using default values (empty string or 1) for missing values.

Comment: Thank you Does that mean **"request.user.get("xxxxxx")** is also pre defined? I assumed there was some form of function overloading going on here. But I am not sure now.

Comment: you example doesn't contain anything related to user, so I can't be 100% sure, but most likely it's similar: a dictionary-like behaviour which can be accessed with get.

Answer (score 2):

Flask sets `request.data` or `request.form` for POST requests, not both.

- `request.form` is populated if Flask understood the POST request.
- `request.data` is populated if Flask couldn't understand the request enough to put the values in `request.form`. This could be a Flask issue or possibly due to a missing or unsatisfactory `Content-type` header.

Therefore you cannot refactor this code to use `.form` because it will be empty.

Both are dictionaries so you can use the optional `.get()` way of access and provide a default value as the second argument.